# Landscape 18.03 - import-gpg-key missingparameter

Tags: landscape

I try to import the `gpg-key`, first I created a file `secret-key.pem` but when I run the command

```
landscape-api import-gpg-key secret-key secret-key.pem
```

the result is

```
Got server error: Status: 400

Error code: MissingParameter

Error message: The request must contain the parameter material (unicode)
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: try `landscape-api import-gpg-key LANDSCAPE_API_KEY secret-key LANDSCAPE_API_SECRET secret-key.pem`

Comment: **not working** `landscape-api import-gpg-key NYKHFVNFWVXXXXXXXXXX secret-key IqkevbYQFPYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY secret-key.pem` output `usage: /usr/bin/landscape-api import-gpg-key name filename` **and** `/usr/bin/landscape-api import-gpg-key: error: unrecognized arguments: IqkevbYQFPYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY secret-key.pem`

Comment: How do you create secret-key.pem? It should be asci armored output like generated by "gpg --export --armor ID_OF_KEY > secret-key.pem"

Comment: before use `landscape-api import-gpg-key` you need to export a GPG secret key using `gpg --export-secret-keys -a KEYID > secret-key.pem`

Comment: KEYID as `IqkevbYQFPYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY` and then you can `export LANDSCAPE_API_SECRET="<API secret key>" `

Comment: i created the `secret-key.pem` with `touch` - now, i know thats is not the rigth way

Comment: when i run `gpg --export-secret-keys -a KEYID > secret-key.pem` with the KEYID `IqkevbYQFPYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY` **i get**  `gpg: WARNING: Nothing exported` **i also get it, when i run** `gpg --export-secret-keys`